# How to sort numbers and strings while keeping the strings in order and in the front and the numbers sorted in the back in JS?

Tags: javascript, sorting

Say I have an array like this:

```
["a", "bb", 1, 2, "z", 4, 3]
```

and I want the result array to be this:

```
["a", "bb", "z", 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How do I write this? I have this as my predicate:

```
export const someBrokenSort = (option1, option2) => {
  const numberOption1 = Number(stripCommas(option1));
  const numberOption2 = Number(stripCommas(option2));
  if (numberOption1 < numberOption2 || isNaN(numberOption1)) return -1;
  if (numberOption1 > numberOption2 || isNaN(numberOption2)) return 1;

  return 0;
};
```

But this results with this:

```
 ["z", "bb", "a", 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: do you like to sort the string as well?

Comment: No I do not need to sort the actual string. "a" just needs to be in the front

Answer (score 6):

You could check the type and move the strings to top.

```js
var array = ["a", "bb", 1, 2, "z", 4, 3];
array.sort((a, b) => 
    (typeof a === 'number') - (typeof b === 'number') ||
    a - b
);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: wouldn't this `(typeof a === 'number') - (typeof b === 'number')` evaluate to `boolean - boolean`?

Comment: @Scrimothy `false` is coerced to `0` with a numerical operator.

Comment: hmm, yeah that's interesting. Clever

Comment: When is the or condition hit?

Comment: Ohhhh true - true == 0 which is falsey nvm.

Comment: @NinaScholz did you try with ["a", "zbb", 1, 0, 2, "z", 4, 3];

Comment: @gaetanoM, i did. what should happen?

Comment: @NinaScholz I assume you do not sort strings. Can you check?

Comment: @gaetanoM, that's right, op wants to keep the order of strings.

Comment: Thanks so much. I became crazy to get the opposite.

Comment: But when there are 2 strings being compared, we still do a - b right? We get false - false which evaluates to 0 which is falsey and so the right side evaluates when a and b are strings right? Is that not what we want?

Comment: @Jwan622, it does not mttter, because the strings are converted to number, this yields `NaN` and the difference is still `NaN` which is interpreted as zero which means that both items are in right order.

Comment: Oh so 0 is the same thing as `NaN`?

Comment: NO! *Not a Number* is not zero. But for [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), every [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value is interpreted as zero.

Answer (score 4):

As a variant:

```js
const arr = ["a", "bb", 1, 2, "z", 4, 3];

const sorted = [
  ...arr.filter(el => typeof el === 'string'),
  ...arr.filter(el => typeof el === 'number').sort(),
];

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Good one, side-note, if we need to sort the string we just need to add sort at the end. var sorted1 = [
  ...arr1.filter(el => typeof el === 'string').sort(),
  ...arr1.filter(el => typeof el === 'number').sort(),
];

Comment: But this way has an overhead of two extra allocated arrays and it does not sort the array in place)

Answer (score 0):

According to return values of [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) compare function my proposal is:

1. string - number  --> string first
2. number - string  --> number after
3. convert to string and compare

```js
var array = ["a", "zbb", 1, 0, 2, "z", 4, 3];
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (typeof a === 'string' && typeof b === 'number') ? -1 :
            (typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'string') ? 1 :
                          a.toString().localeCompare(b.toString());
});

console.log(array);
```